# how program and compile C in eclipse IDE in ubuntu 11.10? which plug in I need to install?

Tags: c, linux, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Which is the plug in I need to install to program C in my eclipse
How I install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install eclipse [CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) (C Development Kit). You can choose which compiler you want to use with CDT. You can read more [here](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/EclipseCpp_HowTo.html).

Comment: could you plese give link that i need to add for installing C Plug in

Comment: You can get the corresponding download links from http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php